# 16.04 Opera Browser: flash

Tags: 16.04, flash, opera

So I can't play flash videos on my 16.04 lts from most sites (imdb trailers for one), yet Youtube plays well (because it is html5 and not fĺash?).
I am confused as to if this is a flash problem or other, I have followed many flash tutorials yet it just won't work (except for youtube, that is).

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: fyi: youtube dropped flash in 2015 as they switched to html5.  I'm sorry I can't help as I don't use flash.

Comment: Thank you!
This does not work, though.

Comment: @wilh3lm: If it "does not work", please provide more details by editing your question. For instance, what's the result if you click the "Check Now" button on [this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html)?

Comment: just a thought - does your cpu support PAE. Flash won't install on non-PAE cpus (on any OS) as it requires pae, and its message is somewhat vague &
 easily missed ('unsupported on this cpu' from memory).  intel were selling non-pae cpu's into 2009 if not later for low-end netbooks etc sold in 2010....

Comment: It is a desktop computer, not so sure how to find out if it is PAE or not.

Answer (score 1):

I changed from Opera Stable to Opera Beta then I could play videos (Twitter, BBC, etc). Also you could try just updating Opera as latest v51 came out a few days ago.